# Elixir, Ecto pattern matching conditional with db query not behaving as expected

Tags: pattern-matching, conditional-statements, elixir, ecto

If the record does not exist, I would expect this conditional to create it, but it does not.... nil is returned.

```
case Repo.get_by(User, %{email: "hulk@hogan.com"}) do
    struct ->
      struct
    nil ->
      params = Map.merge(%{email: "hulk@hogan.com"}, %{password: "password"})
      Repo.insert!(User.changeset(User.__struct__, params))
end

# returns nil.... huwutt???
```

However, if I change the ordering of the condition, it works. What am I missing here?

```
case Repo.get_by(User, %{email: "hulk@hogan.com"}) do
    nil ->
      params = Map.merge(%{email: "hulk@hogan.com"}, %{password: "password"})
      Repo.insert!(User.changeset(User.__struct__, params))
    struct ->
      struct
end

# returns a set of 24" pythons, brother.... huzah!
```

Comment: In your first example, the first case will always be matched since you are not providing any guard, and as such, `struct` will bind to `nil`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/case-cond-and-if.html#case)

> `case` allows us to compare a value against many patterns until we
>   find a matching one:

In another word, the first matching case will run and `case` will not proceed further.

In your first example, the first case will always be matched since you are not providing any guards, and as such, `struct` will bind to `nil`. Your second approach solves the problem because you're pattern matching a specific case first, and then defaulting to a general case by binding the evaluation of `case` to `struct`.

Also note that you can use guards in your first case to make sure that the value of `struct` is a `map` as outlined [here](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/case-cond-and-if.html#expressions-in-guard-clauses).

```
case Repo.get_by(User, %{email: "hulk@hogan.com"}) do
    struct when is_map(struct) ->
      struct
    nil ->
      params = Map.merge(%{email: "hulk@hogan.com"}, %{password: "password"})
      Repo.insert!(User.changeset(User.__struct__, params))
end
```